# Session not really flush,why?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I met a problem.here are my codes(the codes are in Controller):

```
  public function login(Request $request){

    $name = $request->name;
    $pwmd5 = md5($request->pw);
    $result= user::select(DB::raw("CASE WHEN password ='$pwmd5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS passwrod_matches,id,name"))
    ->where('name',$name)
    ->first();

    if ($result == null) {
        return returnFormat('account wrong', false);
    } elseif ($result['password_matches'] == '0') {
        return returnFormat('pw wrong', false);
    };
    $result['password_status'] = '1';
    static::saveUser($result);
    return returnFormat($result);
   }

  static public function saveUser(&$user){

    if(!is_array($user)){
        $user->toArray();
    }
    $user['sid'] = Session::getId();
    session(['user'=>$user]);

   }

public function checkUser(Request $request){

    $user = session('user');
    return $user;

}

public function logout(Request $request){


    session()->flush();
    return returnFormat(true);

}
```

---

what I did is login()-> checkuser()-> logout();
But when I login() with another account,I found that the session Id is exactly the same..why?

Comment: Why should it change? And why don't you use `\Auth` for that stuff?

Comment: Do not use your own authentication logic and do not use md5 for password hashing.  Allow Laravel to handle this for you, you are just going to create an insecure system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three ways to destroy sessions :

1)

```
Session::flush(); // removes all session data
```

2)

```
Session::forget('yourKeyGoesHere') // Removes a specific variable
```

3)

```
Auth::logout() // logs out the user
```